# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: pos'

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit, uitextview

My app is crashing when i paste some copied text in UITextView. This crash occurs only on iOS15

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203feba4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201a1be7 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Foundation                          0x00007fff20753aa2 _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff254164a5 -[_UITextKitTextPosition compare:] + 235
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff254097b4 -[UITextInputController comparePosition:toPosition:] + 85
5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2542ac7d -[UITextView comparePosition:toPosition:] + 85
6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff253d0251 -[UITextPasteController _clampRange:] + 634
7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff253d09c4 __87-[UITextPasteController _performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:forSession:completion:]_block_invoke + 40
8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff253d0bcc __87-[UITextPasteController _performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:forSession:completion:]_block_invoke.174 + 184
9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff25412629 -[UITextInputController _pasteAttributedString:toRange:completion:] + 471
10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff253d092a -[UITextPasteController _performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:forSession:completion:] + 726
11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff253cfc07 __49-[UITextPasteController _executePasteForSession:]_block_invoke + 299
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2011265a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2011383a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20120c88 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1075
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2036c84d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203670aa __CFRunLoopRun + 2772
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203660f3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
18  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2c995cd3 GSEventRunModal + 139
19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff25059f42 -[UIApplication _run] + 928
20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2505eb5e UIApplicationMain + 101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conform your view controller to `UITextPasteDelegate`:

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UITextPasteDelegate { ...
```

And set past delagete:

```
textView.pasteDelegate = self
```

Then implement `textPasteConfigurationSupporting` function:

```
func textPasteConfigurationSupporting(
    _ textPasteConfigurationSupporting: UITextPasteConfigurationSupporting,
    performPasteOf attributedString: NSAttributedString,
    to textRange: UITextRange) 
-> UITextRange {
    <#code#>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but is there any other solution than to bypass the system paste mechanism?

Comment: @tesla I did not understand your question, but for more information, you can search about `canPerformAction` and `UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste`.

Comment: Are you able to find the exact reason for the crash?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution that worked for me. If you use UITextView within a table view and you also implemented prepareForReuse for a cell which contains UITextView. Make sure you set the UITextView.text value to nil in prepareForReuse. In my case I did that later (not in prepareForReuse) and this somehow caused some inconsistency issues regarding "pos" when pasting leading to a crash.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).